# Pass through parameters directly to in-line onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that is the following:

```
$('#myDataTable').on('click', 'i', function(e) {
    //Do stuff
```

I want to be able to directly put an onclick function in the html so I can put the event function in its own function and be able to call it from other places in my codebase. I want to do something like this:

```
<table id="myDataTable"  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" width='100%' onclick="myFunction()>
    <thead><th></th></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I know I can pass parameters through to myFunction() but how do I pass the `i` parameter to my onclick function in the html?

I tried doing `onclick('i')="ticketLogging.removeDomainFromTable()"` which doesn't fire off so I'm assuming its wrong syntax and I can't find any examples online that pass parameters to onclick.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the 'i' in the function where it is called

```
<table id="myDataTable"  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" width='100%' onclick="myFunction('i')">
    <thead><th></th></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Had to refactor my method to add a parameter in the method rather than the onclick though. Curious to see if there is a different answer but this definitely works for me for now

Comment: do you want to pass 'i' param using onclick?